# Count the number of children in my JSON file using JSON.NET with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, json.net

I have an xml with:

```
string xml = "<?xml .... />" +
    "<root>" +
        "<paramFile version=1.0>" +
            "<stuff />" +
        "</paramFile>" +
        "<paramFile version=1.0>" +
            "<stuff />" +
        "</paramFile>" +
     "</root>";
```

Then I convert to JSON and parse it:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc).Replace("\"@", "\"");
    JToken token = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
```

How do I get the count of the number of paramFiles in my JSON?

Comment: Can I just ask, why the need to turn XML to JSON? Are you storing it as JSON somewhere, outputting it etc?

Comment: the XML is legacy in the system, I am turning everything to JSON and there will eventually be no XML. But still need to know how to count the elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this works (And I find is easiest). Mostly depends how deep your tree is going to be.

```
token["root"]["paramFile"].Count();
```

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to System.Linq;